# Оценка алгоритма по времени

Tags: c++, алгоритм, асимптотика

есть алгоритм:

```
Type ScalarProduct(Type v1[], Type v2[], int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    Type sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += v1[i] * v2[i];
    return sum;
}
```

высчитывающий скалярное произведение двух векторов размерности N,нужно было провести серию экспериментов, в которых будет фиксироваться время работы программы для различных значений n

Серию результатов эксперимента предлагаю:

- N=1000,t=0.001
- N=2000,t=0.014
- N=5000,t=0.046
- **N=10000,t=0.004**
- N=20000,t=0.001
- N=50000,t=0.064
- N=100тыс, t=0.002
- N=200тыс, t=0.002
- N=500тыс, t=0.005

***Вопрос: разве может алгоритм при N=500 тысяч, работать быстрее, чем,например при N=2000?????***

Алгоритм, если я правильно разобрался, имеет сложность вида О(n), но на графике, очевидно, никакой линейности не наблюдается.

Способ реализации подсчёта времени работы алгоритма прилагаю:

```
clock_t start = clock();
    cout << ScalarProduct <int>(vect1, vect2, N) << "\n";
    clock_t end = clock();
    cout << "Completed for " << (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " second" << endl;
```

Массивы vect1 и vect2 заполняются рандомно.

Comment: Как вы измеряете время? Какой минимальный отрезок времени может быть измерен вашим способом?

Comment: внёс правку по измерению времени, при n=0,t=0

Comment: печать в поток значений занимает намного больше времени, чем вычисления чисел. Если вы не печатали, то приведите реальный код.

Comment: У вас точности таймера не хватает.

Comment: `cout << ScalarProduct <int>(vect1, vect2, N) << "\n";` предположу, что на небольшом количестве данных, основное время уходит на вывод в консоль

Answer (score 0):

У алгоритма асимптотика линейная. Даже если ты ни в чём не накосячил при замерах, надо было брать значения гораздо больше потому что у таких мелких результатов погрешность больше самого результата.

Бери 100'000'000, 200'000'000, 400'000'000 и т. д. Ну или хотя бы в 10 раз меньше. Нужно чтобы где-то в замерах фигугрировало время около секунды.

---

UPDATE: А в замерах ты накосячил. У тебя вывод на консоль участвует в замере времени. Надо сохранять результат в переменную, а вывод делать уже после окончания замера.

Comment: Правильно ли я вас понял? т.е результаты при таких n имеют высокую погрешность и поэтому график линейности не выстраивается?

Comment: @tnewplayer232, дополнил ответ в соответствии с кодом из замера из вопроса. Скорее всего после исправления у тебя везде будет 0. Кроме последних 3 строк, где уже что-то прорисовывается.

Comment: Если я объявляю N константой, то  вывод на консоль всё равно будет участвовать в замере времени?

Comment: @tnewplayer232, при чём тут вообще n?

Comment: сам вызов потока cout участвует в замере времени?

Comment: @tnewplayer232, да.

Comment: @tnewplayer232, прочитать последние 2 строки ответа и подумать.

Comment: в функцию засунул   unsigned int start_1 = clock(); и    unsigned int end_1 = clock();  перед и после алгоритма, но суть то в чём, я допустим завожу переменную z=end_1-start_1, как мне её из под функции вынести, если в возврате только sum должно быть

Comment: Я чайник, поэтому может и не понимаю простых вещей.